# Setting up iOS Restkit with Django Rest Framework

Tags: ios, django, api, django-rest-framework, restkit

I have an API sitting at this url: https://evening-everglades-1560.herokuapp.com/api/v1/stocks/

I am trying to implement iOS RestKit with like so (this is in MasterViewController.m):

```
RKObjectMapping *stockMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Stock class]];
[stockMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"stockId": @"id"}];
NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:stockMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://evening-everglades-1560.herokuapp.com/api/v1/stocks.json"]];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
        Stock *stock = [result firstObject];
        NSLog(@"mapped w stock: %@", stock);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failed w error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
[operation start];
```

This is what is logged:

```
2016-01-17 16:42:08.233 Stocks[9415:1208281] W restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:99 Adding mapping error: No mappable values found for any of the attributes or relationship mappings
2016-01-17 16:42:08.234 Stocks[9415:1208308] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:250 GET 'https://evening-everglades-1560.herokuapp.com/api/v1/stocks.json' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.4798s mapping=0.0042s total=0.5528s]
2016-01-17 16:42:08.235 Stocks[9415:1208245] mapped w stock: (null)`
```

I am not sure of what to put for the `pathPattern` and `keyPath`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just looks like the mapping is the wrong way round: `@"id": @"stockId"`

Comment: When I switch them I get this error: `valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key stockId.`

Comment: Where did that key come from then? I didn't see it in the JSON I downloaded and you haven't given your object definition

Comment: I was just trying to get something working with Restkit and my API.  I'm not sure how to configure Restkit with this.  Any working example with [this API](https://evening-everglades-1560.herokuapp.com/api/v1/stocks/) would be super useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed thanks to [wain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain) inquiring about "you haven't given your object definition."  I forgot to define submitter in my `stock.h` cocoa class.

Adding `@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *submitter;` to stock.h fixed it.